# attempt to find length of null array but array contains several filenames

Tags: java, android, file, nullpointerexception, android-external-storage

I am trying to get length of an array containing files inside a folder but its saying the array is null.

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        String string1 = adapter.getItem(position);
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ string1;
        File directory = new File(path);
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(files.length), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)  //this line throws NPE exception
            .show();
    }
```

It works fine when I replace `String path1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ string1;`  by
 `String path1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/Pictures";`

Adapter containing `getItem` method :

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> mData;
    private ArrayList<String> mData2;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;
    private Context context;

    // data is passed into the constructor
    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> data, ArrayList<String> data2) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
        this.mData2 = data2;
        this.context = context;
    }

 // inflates the cell layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

  // binds the data to the textview in each cell
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String animal = mData.get(position);
        String animal2 = mData2.get(position);
        int THUMBSIZE = 100;
        Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(animal2),
                THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);
        Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(animal2, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
        holder.myTextView.setText(animal);
            if(animal!= null && animal.endsWith(".mp3")){
                holder.myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.song);
            }
        else if(animal!= null && animal.endsWith(".pdf")){
            holder.myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.pdficon2);
        }
        else
            if(animal!= null && animal.endsWith(".jpeg") && BitmapFactory.decodeFile(animal2)!=null ){
                holder.myImage.setImageBitmap(ThumbImage);
            }
            else
            if(animal!= null && animal.endsWith(".mp4")){
                holder.myImage.setImageBitmap(thumb);
            }
            else
            if(animal!= null && animal.endsWith(".zip")){
                holder.myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.zip);
            }
            else
            if(animal!= null && animal.endsWith(".aac")){
                holder.myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.song);
            }
            else
            if(animal!= null && animal.endsWith(".txt")){
                holder.myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.text);
            }
           else if(animal!= null && animal.endsWith(".apk")){
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageArchiveInfo(animal2, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            if(packageInfo != null) {
                ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageInfo.applicationInfo;
                    appInfo.sourceDir = animal2;
                    appInfo.publicSourceDir = animal2;
                Drawable icon = appInfo.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager());
                Bitmap bmpIcon = ((BitmapDrawable) icon).getBitmap();
                holder.myImage.setImageBitmap(bmpIcon);
            }

        }
            else {
                holder.myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.folder);
            }
        }

// total number of cells
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }


    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView myTextView;
        ImageButton myImage;
        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myImage = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonimage);
            myTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
            myImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

 public String getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.dell_1.Myapp3, PID: 3755
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                                             at com.example.dell_1.myapp3.InternalStorage.onItemClick(InternalStorage.java:43)
                                                                             at com.example.dell_1.myapp3.MyRecyclerViewAdapter$ViewHolder.onClick(MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java:120)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5609)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22263)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Manifest file contains following permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
```

Also, I am asking for permissions at runtime too.

```
private void buttonClicked(View view) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) + ContextCompat
                .checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Snackbar.make(view, "Permission not Granted, Requesting permission.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                Snackbar.make(view, "We need permission to internal storage for displaying songs", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                Snackbar.make(view, "Allow myapp3 to access this device's internal storage", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }
    }


 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(Bacon1.this, "WRITE_CONTACTS granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();


                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(Bacon1.this, "WRITE_CONTACTS Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
```

Comment: You use `files.length`. But files==null. Check before use. That folder contains files. We do believe that. But you are not permitted to read that folder.

Comment: How is it null when it is supposed to contain files inside a folder of external storage ? @greenapps

Comment: Look here as it is same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731256/load-pdf-error-java-io-filenotfoundexception?noredirect=1#comment84461969_48731256

Comment: I have added the permissions @greenapps but I am getting filenotfound in LOGCAT but that doesn't stop it from fetching bitmaps, ALso I am passing filepath inside `decodeFile()`

Comment: `I have added the permissions`. That is only requesting for a permission. But you have to add still extra code for Android 6+ as you could read. Now did you?

Comment: yes I did, I mentioned it in the last line of the question, Now I have included code too @greenapps . i did not want the question to get downvoted for including too much code

Comment: Please never post ephemeral content like paste.ofcode.org on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably need the absolute path of the file. So, instead using:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + string1;
```

Try using:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + string1;
```

Comment: you are right, it doesn't change anything though . Also I tried using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Pictures"; `  but it throws `Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x11`

Comment: Now its working after trying  `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Pictures";` and replacing  `Toast.makeText(this, files.length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) 
                .show();` by   `Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(files.length), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();` ,   not working for string1 still

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission in your manifest to read folder content, otherwise it will return null :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Your folder can be empty anyway, so checking if `value != null` is also a good practice :

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        String string1 = adapter.getItem(position);
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ string1;
        File directory = new File(path);
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        if (files != null){
            Toast.makeText(this, files.length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) //this line throws NPE exception
            .show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you running in emulator ? If so, go to apps setting to check this permission

Comment: Otherwise, there is no files in your `path`

Comment: No, i am running on an actual device

Comment: Even if I replace it by String path = `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Pictures";` , I get same results